# What does this expression means "(^|:)$1($|:)"?

Tags: regex, bash

I have a bash script that contains following line:

```
if ! echo $PATH | /bin/egrep -q "(^|:)$1($|:)" ; then
```

What does "(^|:)$1($|:)" means?

Comment: Start here http://www.regular-expressions.info

Comment: `egrep` is not even needed, you could juse `=~` operator in BASH

Comment: @anubhava: That hardly answers the question what the RE means!

Comment: That's why it was not an answer but a comment, besides regex has already been explained below by dtmilano

Comment: See https://regex101.com/ or http://regexr.com/ etc.

Comment: The most obvious way to reach the documentation is to look at the command - in this case egrep - and look at its documenation, man page, info page or whatever. The first element `(^|:)` means start of line or colon, the last `($|:)` means end of line or colon and `$1` is some string passed to the script. So it is checking if the argument passed is an element of the PATH (or contiguous elements, if it contains `:`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It checks that `$1` is inside `PATH` delimited or by `:` or at the beginning (`^`) or end of it (`$`).